# Programmatically detect and extract an audio envelope

Tags: c, audio, signal-processing

All suggestions and links to relevant info welcome here. This is the scenario:

Let us say I have a .wav file of someone speaking (and therefore all the samples associated with it).

I would like to run an algorithm on the series of samples to detect when an event happens i.e. the beginning and the end of an envelope. I would then use this starting and end point to extract that data to be used elsewhere.

What would be the best way to tackle this? Any pseudocode? Example code? Source code?

I will eventually be writing this in C.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1**

Parsing the wav file is not a problem. But some pseudo-code for the envelope detection would be nice! :)

Comment: Is your question about parsing the contents of a .wav-file? Or about the later signal-processing? Or both perhaps?

Comment: @ Ole Thomsen Buus. Please see EDIT 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual method is:

1. take absolute value of waveform, abs(x[t])
2. low pass filter (say 10 Hz cut-off)
3. apply threshold

Comment: do you have a source for that technique? The `abs()` doesn't make sense to me; for example imagine alternating -1.0 and 1.0 at 440hz. `abs()` would return silence.

Comment: @tenfour : your example doesn't work because your sample rate isn't *above* twice the highest frequency as required according to Nyquist.  And 1.0 isn't silence, it's an amplitude of 1.0 above zero.

Comment: @hotpaw2 why do you assume that? I said it's alternating @ 440hz. So at 44.1khz, the waveform is roughly 100 samples of -1.0, then 100 samples of 1.0. That is a 440hz square wave, which would be converted to silence in this algorithm (right?)

Comment: an endless stream of 1.0 is silence with a DC offset.

Comment: @tenfour: we're trying to detect an *envelope* - the technique is called *rectification* followed by low pass filtering. It's analogous to a diode and an RC low pass filter in the analogue world, much like the way AM is demodulated in simple radio receivers.

Comment: A square wave contains frequencies about Nyquist.  And silence has an envelope unless you specify your question more precisely, way with bandwidth and response time requirements.

Comment: I think I understand. So, in the square wave example, basically we discard all frequency information but preserve amplitude information. The advantage is that it's a cheap calculation, the disadvantage is that we detect all frequencies (including what we would consider DC error) as equally audible. So it would be imperative that you do a DC filter before this operation, to distinguish between inaudible DC offset and the square wave example. @OP: Sorry for hijacking this question!

Comment: @tenfour: yes, although typically the detection threshold will be much higher than any small DC offset, but it might still be wise to have DC blocking, since it's a relatively inexpensive operation.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the same method as an old fashioned analog meter.  Rectify the sample vector, pass the absolute value result though a low pass filter (FIR, IIR, moving average, etc.), than compare against some threshold.  For a more accurate event time, you will have to subtract the group delay time of the low pass filter.

Added: You might also need to remove DC beforehand (say with a high-pass filter or other DC blocker equivalent to capacitive coupling).

Answer (score 1):

Source code of simple envelope detectors can be found in the [Music-DSP Source Code Archive](http://www.musicdsp.org/archive.php?classid=2).

Answer (score 1):

I have written an activity detector class in Java. It's part of my open-source [Java DSP collection](http://www.source-code.biz/dsp/java/).

Answer (score 0):

first order low pass filter C# Code：

```
    double old_y = 0;

    double R1Filter(double x, double rct)
    {
        if (rct == 0.0)
            return 0;
        if (x > old_y)
            old_y = old_y-(old_y - x)*rct/256;
        else
            old_y = old_y + (x - old_y) * rct/256;
        return old_y;
    }
```

When rct=2, it works like this：
[image]

The signal = (ucm + ucm * ma * Cos(big_omega * x)) * (Cos(small_omega1 * x) + Cos(small_omega2 * x) )
where ucm=3,big_omega=200,small_omega1=4,small_omega2=12 and ma=0.8

Pay attention that the filter may change the phase of the base band signal.